# Saving dates from DatePicker in cookies and sending date to Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

As my dev is not available I'm trying to progress with my little JQuery knowledge in my project but I'm facing a blocker. I'm trying to create a cookie that will save the date range selected by the user in datepicker and make the report available in datatable when the user refreshes or return to the page.

All I succeeded to do now is create/refresh the cookie when the dates are selected and make the date range selected back on datepicker when the user returns, but the report is not refreshed for those dates as the Ajax request is not sent to datatable.

Here is my code so far:

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
    "startDate": Cookies.get('startdate'),
    "endDate": Cookies.get('enddate'),
    "opens": "left",
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        $("#datereturn").text(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        var todaydate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"to"+end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        Cookies.set('startdate', start.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        Cookies.set('enddate', end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        $.ajax({
            url:"campaign-table.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{todaydate:todaydate},
            success:function(data){
                $('#campaigntable').html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

I need the Ajax request at the end of the code to be executed at page load. I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work. Shorty, it creates cookies at page load if not existing else it will send the Ajax request to datatable with the dates from the cookies to show the report:

```
$(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var output = 
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day  + '/'
        + d.getFullYear() ;

    if (Cookies.get('startdate')  == null || Cookies.get('enddate') == null) {
          Cookies.set('startdate', output);
          Cookies.set('enddate', output);
    }

    if (Cookies.get('startdate') && Cookies.get('enddate')) {
        var todaydate = Cookies.get('startdate')+"to"+Cookies.get('enddate');
        $.ajax({
            url:"campaign-table.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{todaydate:todaydate},
            success:function(data){
                $('#campaigntable').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: I think that I'm not making the changes at the appropriate place. I have this code that is exactly where the campaign-table.php should load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var todaydate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]+"to"+(new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0];
    $.ajax({
        url:"campaign-table.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{todaydate:todaydate},
        success:function(data){
            $('#campaigntable').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').is(e.target) 
        && $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0 
        && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Where you have 2 if statements try changing second one to be else statement.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: The PHP script `campaign-table.php` `todaydate` expects the range value to be `2020-04-15to2020-04-24`, is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. I have edited my question as I'm maybe trying to send the date range to the table in the wrong code. See code at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need the same functionality that happens when a user selects a date to happen on page load?  That means:

- Check if we already have cookies for existing start/end dates;
- If they exist, use them; if not use some defaults (today?);
- Fire an AJAX request off with those dates;
- Update the data table with the response from the AJAX;

To do this, I'd change just a few minor things:

1) The `daterangepicker` currently uses the existing cookie to set start/end dates.  But this will fail the very first time a user comes to the page, as those cookies don't exist yet.  It would be nice to test and set some defaults here, to handle that case.

2) The AJAX you want to run on page load is exactly the same as what you want to run when a user chooses a date.  So I'd extract that out into a common function you can reference in each place you need it, to avoid duplicating code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create a simple function to fire the AJAX using the date you specify,
    // and show the response on the page.  We can reference this whenever we
    // need to do that.
    function showReport(todaydate) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"campaign-table.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{todaydate:todaydate},
            success:function(data){
                $('#campaigntable').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    // Check if we have cookies with dates, if not, set them to defaults
    // (today for both).  Now when the date range picker uses the
    // cookies the very first time a user visits, it will work.
    if (Cookies.get('startdate') == null || Cookies.get('enddate') == null) {
        Cookies.set('startdate', (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
        Cookies.set('enddate', (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
    }

    var todaydate = Cookies.get('startdate') + "to" + Cookies.get('enddate');

    // We have our dates, fire off the AJAX, and display the response.
    // This runs on page load, as you need.
    showReport(todaydate);

    // Now initialise the date range picker
    $('#demo').daterangepicker({
        // ... all your options, unchanged ...
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        $("#datereturn").text(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        var todaydate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"to"+end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        Cookies.set('startdate', start.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        Cookies.set('enddate', end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

        // Fire off the AJAX with the selected dates and show the response.
        showReport(todaydate);
    });
});
```

You don't need the code quoted in your question starting with `$(function(){`, the stuff we just added to `$(document).ready(function(){` now handles that.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I did how you instruct but it seems that something is wrong as the days in DatePicker are now replaced by NaN. The instructions after function(start, end, label) are not clear. I've only added the line starting with $("#datereturn") and the line after. Is that correct?

Comment: @CreekBarbara I've updated the `function(start, end, label)` section in my answer to make it clearer - the only change there from the code in your question is to delete the `$.ajax({ ... });` section, and add the call to our new function to actually do that AJAX part: `showReport(todaydate);`.  If you're still having trouble, check your browser's dev console, see if there are any errors reported.

Comment: I've done exactly the same as your code. I still have the NaN. This is the error I see in the console "Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "scale(NaN) translate". When I choose a custom rage the dates are back and when I refresh the dates are preselected, but the report is not loading.

Comment: Edit: I changed set.cookie date format and I don't have the Nan problem anymore, but the report still don't load when cookie dates are used

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change the dates in the third code in my question, because that's where the call to there report occurring when loading the page.

Comment: @CreekBarbara I am not sure wha tyou mean about `set.cookie` - your code does not use that anywhere, and so neither does my answer.  Did you mean `Cookies.set()`, which is the syntax you used in the question?

Comment: @CreekBarbara Ah! OK, glad you cracked it, and glad to help! :-)